# Jaspersoft studio - Dynamic height and centering of list content inside a table

Tags: jasper-reports, centering

I'm new to jasper so I'm not sure if I have the right approach. I'm trying to edit a report to better match our new design.

To do this I've merged what was 2 tables into 1, so that the other table would expand with the other even though it lacked content. This worked but it would only print the first object of its content. To solve this I put it inside a list, now I'm receiving all the content but I no longer have dynamic height.

Here's some picture, hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve!
Don't mind the black, just some censored text for testing.

What I'm getting at this moment.

[image: allContent]

This is what I had in mind, all content visible and dynamically aligning to the center of the available space.

[image: finalVersion]

The way I have it setup right now is that this data I'm working with is in a subreport, inside this subreport I have a list object that contains a frame and a table, inside the table I have lists in appropriate columns containing textfields that gets data from each cell that is filled.

What can I do differently?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. Both of the screenshots look similar. So, couldn't figure out what are you looking for.

Comment: In the left column RISK a risk will be described, this content is dynamic so it will differ in height. In the right column MEASURE different suggestions to solve this risk will be presented, each with a unique id. 

What I’m trying to achieve is that these to fields should be of the same height but the content in measure should be centralized vertically. So with only 1 measure the id will take up the whole field, with 2 measures they will each get 50% of the field etc. with a minimum space that all content is visible, since this content is also dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use 'groups' option provided by jasper reports.They help in organizing data on report in a logical manner.A report group(RISK in your case) represents a sequence of consecutive records that have something in common, like the value of a certain report field. So, you can see your report as:

[image]

I could see number of advantages with this design:

1. The display area will be bigger for both the fields - risk and measure.
2. The design will be dynamic.You don't need to worry about the no of measures.
3. The data will be more organized and easy to visualize.
4. Each risk can be made to appear on a separate page.
5. The group footer is associated with the group which can be used to display no of measures available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This is almost how we have it setup right now. Trying to redesign it because we have changed the design in the application which generates the report, so we have the same design languagues through the whole product. 

I'm almost done with the design now, I've changed the Table to Frames, everything that should be on the same row in the same Frame. It's not exactly as I set out to do but it's close enough with this approach. The only thing I'm not able to achieve is to dynamically center the content vertically depending on the available space.